# django tables2 - sum of foreign key based on filter

Tags: python, django, sum, aggregate, django-tables2

Is there a way to sum foreign keys objects based on django table filter?

Example:

```
class Invoice(models.model):
     some_column_1 = models.Decimal(...)
     some_column_2 = models.Decimal(...)

class Payment(models.Model):
     invoice = models.ForeingKey(Invoice, related_name='invoice_payments')
     price = models.Decimal(...)
     date_payed = models.DateField(...)

class InvoiceTable(tables.Table):
     some_column_1 = tables.Column(accessor = some_column_1)
     payments = = tables.Column(accessor = invoice_payments)
     class Meta:
          model = Invoice

class InvoiceFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
     date_from = django_filters.DateFilter(name="invoice__payments__date_payed", lookup_type='gte')
     date_to = django_filters.DateFilter(name="invoice__payments__date_payed", lookup_type='lte')
     model = Invoice
```

I need in InvoiceTable payments column have sum of payments  in this date range. It is possible ?